# Doubt related to the use of Gaussian Surfaces

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

My textbook says we need to take care not to let the Gaussian Surface pass through any discrete charge. However, the Gaussian Surface can pass through a continuous charge distribution.

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point charges correspond to a discontinuous charge distribution. For instance if your surface is a sphere of radius $r$ enclosing a uniform charge distribution $\rho_0$, then the enclosed charge is perfectly defined ans is a continuous function of $r$ ($Q(r) = 4/3 \pi r^3 \rho_0$) so when using the macroscopic Gauss equation the RHS will be defined and regular.

However, if there is a single point charge $q$ on top at $r=R$, suddenly you will have a discontinuity as $Q(R-\varepsilon) \simeq 4/3 \pi R^3$ but $Q(R+\varepsilon) \simeq 4/3 \pi R^3 + q$. For this reason, it does not really make sense to associate a precise enclosed charge for $r=R$, because the limits $r=R^-$ and $r=R^+$ are different. All of this comes from the fact that the charge density $\rho(r)$ diverges at the position of a point charge.